# How to set different time zones in foreach loop?

Tags: php, date, time

I am wanting to enter game times for different baseball teams. I am wanting to use a `foreach` loop like below. PHP will set the time zone to `America/New_York` for all of the loops.

```
$BaseballTeams = array('America/New_York' => 'Maryville College', 'America/Chicago' => 'LeMoyne-Owen College', 'America/Denver' => 'Utah State', 'Pacific/Honolulu' => 'Hawaii Tech');

foreach ($BaseballTeams as $Key => $Value){

  date_default_timezone_set($Key); //Set the time zone for this team.

  //Make a time stamp for that time zone
  $TimeStamp = mktime($Hour,$Minute,$Second,$Month,$Day,$Year);

  //Make a time stamp for that time zone
  $MySQLi -> query("UPDATE Games SET GameDate = $TimeStamp WHERE TeamName = $Value");
}
```

Comment: The timestamp for Hawaii Tech gets entered as a New York time. I tried using the offset functions but I can't get them to work right.

    $Offset = new DateTime('2015-5-21', new DateTimeZone($HomeTeamTimeZone));
    echo $Offset->getOffset();

Comment: Also, it looks like you update the same records each time through the loop.

Comment: One issue I see is `$Value` isn't quoted in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Find the offset from UTC. The offset is an object. You have got to assign it to the offset var. It then becomes an integer. Then make the gametime using gmmktime minus the offset.

Easy-peasy it turns out. But I've been working on this for days and days.

```
    // --------------------------------------------------
    // ### Find the offset between utc and the home team time zone. ###
    // --------------------------------------------------
    $Offset = new DateTime($Year.'-'.$Month.'-'.$Day, new DateTimeZone($HomeTeamTimeZone));
    // --------------------------------------------------
    // ### Offset is a type object. Assigning to offset var turns it into an integer. ###
    // --------------------------------------------------
    $Offset = $Offset->getOffset();
    // --------------------------------------------------
    // ### Use greenwich mean time for the timestamp less the offset (which is in seconds). ###
    // --------------------------------------------------
    $GameTime = gmmktime($Hour, $Minute, 1, $Month, $Day, $Year)-$Offset;
```